# How align text in a spinner center and how to set the text color

Tags: java, android, xml

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:entries="@array/country_arrays"
        android:prompt="@string/country_prompt"
        android:background="@drawable/grey"
        android:layout_weight="1"    
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"   
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />

        android:layout_gravity="center"
```

is not working. Is there any way to do that? and also how to change the text color.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Align spinner text to center](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23776206/align-spinner-text-to-center)

Answer (score 0):

Try with android:gravity="center" instead of android:layout_gravity="center" and put it inside spinner code!

favorite

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:entries="@array/country_arrays"
    android:prompt="@string/country_prompt"
    android:background="@drawable/grey"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"    
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"   
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using

```
android:layout_gravity="center"  //for setting layout in center of screen
```

use

```
android:gravity="center" //for setting values of view in center
```

Comment: you want to change text color too?? then i suggest use custom adapter for spinner..so you can set style as you want..